# Full width of component within SAP Fiori Launchpad

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Is it possible to configure a component which is embedded in a launchpad to use the full width of the screen?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The manifest.json needs to be adjusted like that:

```
...
"sap.ui": {
    "fullWidth": true
    ...
}
...
```

References:

https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/topic/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da

https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/full-screen/

https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/letter-boxing/

Answer (score -1):

The answer is: **you shouldn't.**
...to keep in line with SAP's UX strategy. If it comes to standard apps you are breaking the UX between your apps. If you requirement is to build a large and complex app which requires that width you are also failing UX strategy... just keep that in mind ;-)

Comment: While I agree that we should avoid building a large and complex app for multiple purposes (\*cough\* sapgui \*cough\*), we should keep in mind that [letterboxing is an **optional** feature](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/letter-boxing/). It depends on the floor plan. E.g. apps with Flexible Column Layout are [encouraged to turn the letterboxing **off**](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/flexible-column-layout/#letterboxing).